# Mockup application for application with many pages?

Tags: mockups

I have been using Balsamiq to create mockups for a new application. It has been working very well initially, but now it feels like the application is becoming to large for Balsamiq.

I have connected many Balsamiq screens with the link function in Balsamiq. But that forces me to create way too many screens. Every click makes me create a completely new screen. So if I want to change a button that I am using on many linked screens, then I have to change all of them.

Is there a different application for creating mockups that doesn't force me to create new mockups for every click? I don't know exactly what I'm looking for but maybe something where only parts of the mockup application change when I click on a link?

There is also no functionality in Balsamiq for maintaining my mockups in a structure. Maybe that would help as well. What I'm looking for in essence is an application that let's me mockup more complex applications with many clicks and pages.

Answer (score 1):

[WireframeSketcher](http://wireframesketcher.com) is a wireframe tool that has projects and lets you organize mockups in directories. It's based on Eclipse IDE and so it shares the same advanced way of organizing files. WireframeSketcher also supports refactoring which makes it easy to move files around or rename them without breaking links.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using ["symbols"](http://support.balsamiq.com/customer/portal/articles/110439-working-with-symbols) in Balsamiq, that may help you out some.  What you can do is take any group and make it a symbol.  Then you can use the symbols on multiple pages.  If you want to change the button in multiple places, all you have to do is change the symbol once, and the changes will be carried out throughout the rest of your design.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

[MockupScreens](http://MockupScreens.com) has "master screens", similar to master slides in PowerPoint. You do create new screens technically, but you don't do them from scratch.

Since they derive most of their content from the master, you edit only the differences: value in some field, for example.

(I am m.screens developer)